# Polynomial interpolant as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification, interpolation, interpolation-theory

I need a check on the following exercise:

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a smooth function and consider the data $(0,f(0)), (\epsilon,f(\epsilon))$ and $(1,f(1))$. Let $p(x)$ the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ of the polynomial interpolant of the data.
>
> i) What is the degree of $p(x)$?
>
> ii) What data does $p(x)$ interpolate?
>
> iii) What data does $p'(x)$ interpolate?

---

Here's my attempt:

**i,ii)**
I consider Newton's interpolation for the sets of three points. Using divided difference table, I obtain the Newton polynomial $$P(x)=f(0) + \Bigl(\frac{f(\epsilon)-f(0)}{\epsilon} \Bigr) x + \Bigl( \frac{f(1)-f(\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon} - \frac{f(\epsilon)- f(0)}{\epsilon} \Bigr) x(x-\epsilon)$$

As $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, I note that there are several differential quotients, so $$p(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} P(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + (f'(1) - f'(0))x^2$$

Therefore:

- The degree of $p(x)$ is two.
- $p(x)$ interpolates the points $(0,f(0))$ and $(1,f(0)+f'(1))$

**iii)** $$p'(x)=f'(0) + 2 (f'(1)-f'(0))$$ so $p'(x)$ interpolates $(0,f'(0))$ and $(1, 2f'(1)-f'(0))$

---

Is everything okay, or am I missing something?

Comment: That looks good and is interesting as not so intuitive (I least for me!).

Comment: thanks for the check. Why isn't it "intuitive"? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: Just that without writing on paper, I won’t have say what $p(1)$ would be!

Comment: Oh, right, that's weird... maybe there's something that I'm missing, but I can't find any flaw @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: No, what you did is fine!

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the check! :) It could be a topic for your site actually (lol) :-) @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: $p(x)$ is not $p(1)$ when $x=1$. This is abnormal.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: fine but wrong ?!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't understand. I get $P(1)=f(1)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: please show me.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $P(1)=f(0) + \Bigl(\frac{f(\epsilon)-f(0)}{\epsilon} \Bigr) 1 + \Bigl( \frac{f(1)-f(\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon} - \frac{f(\epsilon)- f(0)}{\epsilon} \Bigr) 1(1-\epsilon)=f(0) + \Bigl(\frac{f(\epsilon)-f(0)}{\epsilon} \Bigr) +(f(1)-f(\epsilon))-- \frac{f(\epsilon)- f(0)}{\epsilon} + f(\epsilon) -f(0)=f(1)$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I am talking about $p(1)$, but your evaluation of $P(1)$ is missing a term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a slight error,
$$
\lim_{ϵ→0}\frac{f(1)-f(ϵ)}{1-ϵ}=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=f(1)-f(0).
$$
You will not get $f'(1)$ at this place, and thus anywhere else in the ensuing formulas. You could apply the mean value theorem, but that would introduce an unknown midpoint.

Comment: Right,  thanks for the correction. :-) Btw, so $p'$ interpolate $(0,f'(0)$ and $(1,2f(1)-2f(0) - f'(0))$, right? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @LutzLehmann

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, in the limit $p(x)$ must interpolate $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ (as $f(\epsilon)$ converges to $f(0)$), and $p'(x)$ must interpolate $f'(0)$ as $p$ interpolates two infinitesimally close points.

Fixing your formula,

$$p_\epsilon(x)=f(0) + \frac{f(\epsilon)-f(0)}{\epsilon} x + \Bigl( \frac{f(1)-f(\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon} - \frac{f(\epsilon)- f(0)}{\epsilon} \Bigr) x(x-\epsilon)$$

tends to

$$p(x)=f(0) +f'(0) x + \Bigl( f(1)-f(0) - f'(0) \Bigr) x^2,$$

which fulfills the above findings.

In blue, the function $\sin2x$. In magenta, interpolation with $\epsilon=0.1$ and in green, $\epsilon=0$.

[image]